# An algorithm to check and replace missing data between 2 timeseries data

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I am new in this platform and R as well.

I have 2 datasets with (datasetA)70000 rows and (datasetB)10000 rows. A and 
B are identical datasets and have 18 variables. 
I need to find missing data from  datasetA and replace (if exist) it from datasetB with the same timestamp.

I have tried merge, join, match.

I want to keep first dataset and replace missing data from second dataset.

Is there any solution without loop?

```
DatasetA
            Date     Time qK1 qL1 vP1 vL1 qK2
34900 20.06.2019 05:40:00  --  --  --  --  --
34901 20.06.2019 05:41:00  10   4 140  86   9
34902 20.06.2019 05:42:00  --  --  --  --  --
34903 20.06.2019 05:43:00   8   0 130   0   6
34904 20.06.2019 05:44:00  --  --  --  --  --
34905 20.06.2019 05:45:00  --  --  --  --  --
34906 20.06.2019 05:46:00   6   2 132  87   9
34907 20.06.2019 05:47:00  --  --  --  --  --
34908 20.06.2019 05:48:00  --  --  --  --  --
34909 20.06.2019 05:49:00   8   1 127  84   3
34910 20.06.2019 05:50:00  --  --  --  --  --
34911 20.06.2019 05:51:00  --  --  --  --  --
34912 20.06.2019 05:52:00  10   4 116 104   9
34913 20.06.2019 05:53:00  --  --  --  --  --
34914 20.06.2019 05:54:00   6   0 125   0  11
34915 20.06.2019 05:55:00  --  --  --  --  --
34916 20.06.2019 05:56:00  --  --  --  --  --
34917 20.06.2019 05:57:00   5   4 130  93   7
34918 20.06.2019 05:58:00  --  --  --  --  --
34919 20.06.2019 05:59:00  --  --  --  --  --
34920 20.06.2019 06:00:00  --  --  --  --  --


DATASETB
                    Date  Time qK1 qL1 vP1 vL1 qK2
340 20.06.2019 05:39   5   1 123  88   7
341 20.06.2019 05:40   9   1 115 110   9
342 20.06.2019 05:41  10   4 140  86   9
343 20.06.2019 05:42   7   1 102  87   7
344 20.06.2019 05:43   8   0 130   0   6
345 20.06.2019 05:44   6   0 121   0   6
346 20.06.2019 05:45   7   0 122   0   9
347 20.06.2019 05:46   6   2 132  87   9
348 20.06.2019 05:47   4   1 128 101   6
349 20.06.2019 05:48   6   2 124  92   9
350 20.06.2019 05:49   8   1 127  84   3
351 20.06.2019 05:50   7   1 115  87   7
352 20.06.2019 05:51   7   0 130   0   4
353 20.06.2019 05:52  10   4 116 104   9
354 20.06.2019 05:53   9   1 126  85   8
355 20.06.2019 05:54   6   0 125   0  11
356 20.06.2019 05:55   5   1 125  86   8
357 20.06.2019 05:56   6   5  87  93   9
358 20.06.2019 05:57   5   4 130  93   7
359 20.06.2019 05:58   7   2 124  86   9
360 20.06.2019 05:59   5   1 120  89   7

I tried this basically, but it doesnt work due to length difference. 

DatasetA$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(DatasetA$Date, DatasetA$Time), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
DatasetB$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(DatasetB$Date, DatasetB$Time), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
DatasetA[DatasetA$timestamp==DatasetB$timestamp,"qK1"]<-DatasetB$qK1

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, DatasetA$timestamp == DatasetB$timestamp, "qK1",  : 
  replacement has 10080 rows, data has 60482
In addition: Warning message:
In `==.default`(DatasetA$timestamp, DatasetB$timestamp) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Please give an example data set (e.g. `dput(head(datasetA))`). Are you missing rows in A, or just individual values?

Comment: I already submit example datasets within question. There is no missing raw at all. But there are missing values regarding each variables. To find out i, j logic and replace took longer loops. Is it possible to do it in short way?

Comment: There are no example data sets which I can load. Please use the output of `dput()`, so I can paste the data set in my R session and try things with it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I try to output dput but it takes long text. Instead i put a wide sample which may give you a reference.

Comment: As i described at the questions datasets are bigdata. There are off course match for time stamps. Otherwise meaningless to work on this.This is just sample for 2 datasets to understand the concept not only for you but also answer below.

Comment: No one asked you to post the complete data sets; I only wanted a minimal, *reproducible* example. Was finding two examples where the time stamps match really so hard?

Answer (score 0):

```
    DatasetA$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(DatasetA$Date, DatasetA$Time), 
    format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    DatasetB$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(DatasetB$Date, DatasetB$Time),
    format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")

    rownames(DatasetA)<-DatasetA$timestamp
    rownames(DatasetB)<-DatasetB$timestamp

    nas <- which(is.na(DatasetA), arr.ind=TRUE)
    nas.map <- data.frame(Row=rownames(DatasetA)[nas[,1]], 
                Col=colnames(DatasetA)[nas[,2]])

    for(i in 1:nrow(nas.map)) {
       DatasetA[ as.character(nas.map[i,1]) , as.character(nas.map[i,2]) ] <-
       DatasetB[ as.character(nas.map[i,1]) , as.character(nas.map[i,2])]
    }
```

Thanks a lot @January. I solved the question by your suggestion. Only I did small edit inside the loop (as.character) and it takes about 2 min to finish for 140000 missing data.